# Docker's ability to create multi-arch images, how does that play with best security practices?

Tags: docker

Within `docker-compose.yml`, you can point to a specific docker image and tag and the Docker will pick the correct image based on the host's architecture, i.e. arm64 vs amd64.  We've all learned that in order to be secure, you should point to an image tag as well as a specific SHA so that you *always* download the same one due to tags being mutable.  But those SHAs are for specific architectures.  So how are people now configuring their docker-compose.yml files to work on different architectures?

Within our engineering team, we created a small script that wraps `docker-compose` to derive which arch the host is on, and then we maintain secondary `docker-compose.yml` files that are arch-specific and point to the correct image SHAs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. Basically, nothing has changed. Before, you had one tag, now you have N tags depending on how many architectures you support. But the core concept is the same.

Just to add an example, take [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres?tab=tags&page=1) image for example. Check the tags, and you can see that `latest` also has 8 different hashes for different architectures.

And if your question is rather about how to use the same compose file for different architectures, you can just use environment variables for the tags and have different configuration files. Have a look at https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: At the moment, you can tell docker to pull down the a specific tag of postgres and it will pick the correct image based on your host architecture. But the problem is that you can't actually declare the SHA you want to use for each of the different archs without having to use scripting or environment variables to derive that yourself.  I'm wondering if there is a "right" way to do this or do we just have script ourselves out of this situation? Why wouldn't Docker already allow you to do this? It is bad security practice to _not_ specify  the SHA.

Comment: but that's the point. Using postgres as example again, if I pull `sha256:2fb0a6ba2c62bb922fb83a441048ef236538354f4873d33054bbedfcbbff0550`, I know I'm pulling the current `latest` tag for `amd64`. Meanwhile, if I pull `sha256:f6abc4998ad9dccde0ef8542382a591562d0e0846958ae019e4bc0b55c4ec68e`, I know it's `14.2-bullseye` for `arm/v5`.

Comment: in other words, Docker already provides you a right solution, environment variables, and then you could have `amd64.env`, `arm.env` or whatever. However, you are looking for a different solution because you consider that's not right. There is only one SHA per image, so there is no SHA that can't fit all architectures (which is what you are looking for), as that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, when Docker does the right thing when you don't provide a SHA hash. It will introspect the system, figure out the architecture, and then install the correct image for that architecture. Awesome, well done Docker!  But the security contious engineer would never just point to a tag because tags are mutible and the underlying image can change.  So you want to point to a specific SHA which is also a specific arch variant. Okay, so that means I need to create 2 different lists of images and then use my own introspecting script to figure out which one to use.  If that is the only way, fine.

Answer (score -1):

docker-compose can be called from every directory that contain a Dockerfile for example

```
#42sh: ls
-> Dockerfile
#42sh: docker-compose build    
-> Building...!
```